# Combining functors and lambdas

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, functor

I have a functor that creates a linearly spaced set of values . . .

```
//Linear spaced generator
struct gen_lin {
    float mi, inc;
public:
    gen_lin(float _mi=1.f, float _inc=1.f) : mi(_mi), inc(_inc){};
    float operator()() {
        return  mi+=inc;
    }
};
```

And I can fill a vector with values like so ...

```
const size_t elements = 400;
std::vector<float> x(elements);
std::generate_n(x.begin(), elements, gen_lin(10.f,5.f) );
```

Now, I can easily convert this to a log scale using a lambda like so ...

```
auto lin = gen_lin(10.f,5.f);
std::generate_n(x.begin(), elements, [&](){return logf(lin());} );
```

But when I try to squeeze it all on to one line, the vector is entirely filled with the value of logf(10.)

```
std::generate_n(x.begin(), elements, [](){return logf(  gen_lin(10.f,5.f)() );} );
```

Why, and is it possible to tweak my last line of code to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this, you are creating a single gen_lin object, and using it multiple times:

```
auto lin = gen_lin(10.f,5.f);
std::generate_n(x.begin(), elements, [&](){return logf(lin());} );
```

With this, you are creating several gen_lin objects:

```
std::generate_n(x.begin(), elements, [](){return logf(  gen_lin(10.f,5.f)() );} );
```

Each time you create a new gen_lin object, the current value gets reset.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case:

```
auto lin = gen_lin(10.f,5.f);
std::generate_n(x.begin(), elements, [&](){return logf(lin());} );
```

You have a persistent `gen_lin` object, `lin`, that gets updated with every call to the lambda.  But with your one-liner, you are just creating fresh `gen_lin` object with every call to the lambda, getting the first value that it returns, and then throwing the object away.  Since it's a fresh object, initialized with the same constant values, it's going to give you the same value every time.

Answer (score 1):

Each lamdas call creates a new instance of your functor in the second case.

Stuff like bind might fix your problem.  Make the lambda take your functor as an argument and use bind to attach a common instance to that argument?

Or use a compose functor of whatever flavour.